# look up username in view on cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I want to be able to display a user's username with cakephp in my default.ctp view. Using the authComponent I know I can look up the userid, but how can I use this to look up the username from the users table? I'm used to doing this from a controller, I'm not sure how to do it within a view.

```
users table
userid |  username
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already know how to do it within a controller - then you're done 99% of the battle. You just need to pass your user that you retrieved in the controller to the view.

**In your controller:**

```
$user = $this->User->read(null, $this->Auth->user('id'));
$this->set('user', $user);
```

**In your view:**

```
<?php echo $user['User']['username']; ?>
```

This is very basic Cake stuff, you should spend a little more time on the manual :)

Comment: I know how to do it through a controller, I just meant not when it's going to default.ctp. Does that go to the pagescontroller?

Comment: Whenever you use `$this->set()`, that data will be available to both your layout and your view. If you want it displayed on all pages, you'll want to put it in your [AppController](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#the-app-controller)'s `beforeFilter()` method.

Comment: Also the pages controller included with Cake is generally used for static content, you should create your own controllers instead of using the PageController ;)

Comment: Thanks for helping out a cake newbie. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with CakePHP. But in any MVC framework, you should *never* access the database from your view. The correct way to handle this is to have the **Controller** tell the **View** which data (which is usually from a **Model**) to display.

For more information about MVC within CakePHP, check [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/cakephp-overview/understanding-model-view-controller.html).

Comment: You don't get the controller to tell the view which model to display (are you familiar with MVC?). The controller interacts with the model to fetch data, process it if need be, and pass that data to the view.

Comment: My explanation was a little too short, my apologies. I've edited my answer that it's data and not jus the model. I'm familiar with several MVC frameworks, wouldn't be posting if I weren't. For most actions however, the data is the model or are a group models. Take a profile page for example, I'd have the controller fetch a Profile model, and send that to the View. In more advanced MVC-frameworks, this enabled autocompletion and support for refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

As of cake 3.6.X this is a sample of what I am using for cake 3 in onder too make a logout buttons that prints the username of the authenticated user

```
    <?php
        $usert=$this->request->getsession()->read('Auth.User');
    //then you can print the 'username' by
        echo $user['username'];
    ?>
```

in previous versions of cake these functions were available but now are with deprecation notice:

```
    $usert=$this->request->session()->read('Auth.User');
    $usert=$this->Session->read('Auth.User');
```